# How can I obtain SNMP OID from Arista in right way?

Tags: snmp, arista

What is right way for obtain Oid from Arista?
I need obtain temperature from the switch. From this I find out that CPU sensor OID is .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.100006001:

```
  switch#show snmp mib walk .1 | grep "sensor"
ENTITY-MIB::entPhysicalDescr[100006001] = STRING: Cpu temp sensor

switch#sh snmp mib translate SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.100006001
**.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.100006001**
```

But when I do snmpwalk I see this result:

```
SnmpWalk.exe -r:*ip_address* -v:3 -ap:md5 -sn:**** -aw:**** -pp:des -****  -os:.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.0 -op:.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5

OID=.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0, Type=OctetString, Value=Arista Networks EOS version 4.25.4M running on an Arista Networks DCS-7050SX3-48YC8
OID=.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0, Type=OID, Value=1.3.6.1.4.1.30065.1.3011.7050.3741.3.48.1654.8
OID=.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0, Type=TimeTicks, Value=6 days, 13:10:26.77
OID=.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0, Type=OctetString, Value=
Total: 4
```

I don't see .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1. How can I get a cpu temperature of the switch?

Comment: ENTITY-MIB::entPhysicalDescr is 1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.2

Comment: If you want that OID, then *ask for it*. (snmpget, not walk.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the information in ENTITY-SENSOR-MIB::entPhySensorTable (1.3.6.1.2.1.99.1.1, RFC 3433) together with the descriptions in ENTITY-MIB::entPhysicalDescr (1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.2, RFC 4133)

In particular, it looks like you want 1.3.6.1.2.1.99.1.1.1.4.100006001